# Error 3034 occurs in EF 5.0 when using TPT inheritance and many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, many-to-many, entity-framework-5

I have 3 step inheritance 
abstract Entity
abstract ApplicationEntity:Entity
abstract SystemEntity:ApplicationEntity

the system entity contains a many to many navigation property which when I try to load I get (202,10) : error 3034: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 202, 208:Two entities with different keys are mapped to the same row. Ensure these two mapping fragments do not map two groups of entities with different keys to the same group of rows.

(208,10) : error 3034: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 208, 578:Two entities with different keys are mapped to the same row. Ensure these two mapping fragments do not map two groups of entities with different keys to the same group of rows.

please help me

Comment: are you doing code first?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post a solution here, but this may not fit your problem as this is for code first approach.

Solution was actually pretty simple. Just dress the base and derived classes with a unique table name, EF will represent each class as a separate table.

In practice (using VB but you get the point if C#):

the base class

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

Namespace Models
    <Table("Notification")>
    Public MustInherit Class NotificationBase
        Public Property ID As Integer
        ...
    End Class
End Namespace
```

a derived class

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema

Namespace Models
    <Table("EmergencyNotification")>
    Public NotInheritable Class EmergencyNotifications
        Inherits NotificationBase
        ...
    End Class
End Namespace
```